# tensorflow multiple regression error

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression

```
import tensorflow as tf
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,5])
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5,1]), name = 'weight')
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name = 'bias')
y = tf.matmul(X, w) + b
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(Y-y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cost)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

x_train = Xfortrain
y_train = Yfortrain

for i in range(10000):
    cost_val, hy_val, _ = sess.run([cost,y,train_step], feed_dict = {X: 
x_train, Y: y_train})

print('w0:%f' % sess.run(w[0]))
print('w1:%f' % sess.run(w[1]))
print('w2:%f' % sess.run(w[2]))
print('w3:%f' % sess.run(w[3]))
print('w4:%f' % sess.run(w[4]))
print('b:%f' % sess.run(b))
```

In this code, Xfortrain is a 278*5 list, and Yfortrain is a 278*1 list. I keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (278, 5) for Tensor 
'Placeholder_23:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'
```

I did many researches but couldn't solve the problem. I know it's an architecture error but I don't know what code to solve it. I am new to tensorflow, and I want to use it for solving the multiple regression model. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I ran your code it works fine. It could be that you might have loaded `Xfortrain` and `Yfortrain` incorrectly. I am posting my code in the answer section. Have a look.

Comment: Can you post the `Xfortrain` and `Yfortrain` variables value?

Answer (score 1):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,5])
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5,1]), name = 'weight') 
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), name = 'bias')
y = tf.matmul(X, w) + b
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(Y-y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

x_train = np.asarray(np.random.normal(size = (278,5))) # using random values from normal distribution to create some training data
weights = np.random.randint(100,size = (5,1)) #generate weights
a = np.dot(x_train, weights) # matrix multiplication
y_train = a + np.random.normal(size = (278,1))# add some noise to the data

for i in range(10000):
    cost_val, hy_val, _ = sess.run([cost,y,train_step], feed_dict = {X: 
x_train, Y: y_train})

print('w0:%f' % sess.run(w[0]))
print('w1:%f' % sess.run(w[1]))
print('w2:%f' % sess.run(w[2]))
print('w3:%f' % sess.run(w[3]))
print('w4:%f' % sess.run(w[4]))
print('b:%f' % sess.run(b))
```

Comment: works. Upvoted, Can you add some details on what is the difference between yours and Song wu's code. and how it helped fix the problem?

Comment: The code structure is mostly the same. When I saw the error I suspected there is something wrong with the train data. So I created some random data with the required dimensions/shape and the code worked. As I mentioned in the comments, I added the code just to demonstrate that the code works fine and there's probably something wrong with the feed data.

Comment: I think there is some shape issue with the original code. As you have generated random variables meeting the shape requirement of the code hence your code is working.

Comment: Hi Clock and Vikash, thank you for the help, it is extremely weird because the code indeed works fine, but when it run on my training data then the error occurs. I have double checked my training data and they are indeed correct. Kind of helpless....

Comment: @SongWu, are you, somewhere in your code, accidently changing the dimensions of any placeholder variables? Before you use your training data and run the optimizer, check the shape of `Yfortrain`

Comment: yeah share the shape of both the variables.

Comment: God.. Really my bad, I accidentally set Yfortrain to the array of Xfortrain... So sorry about the confusion